# how to use d3.rollups in IE11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, internet-explorer-11

```
var bias = d3.rollups(data, function (v) { return d3.sum(v, function(d){ return d.value * Math.min(0, signs.get(d.category))})},
                function(d){ return d.name })
          .sort(function(a, b){d3.ascending(a[1], b[1])})
```

This source code not working in IE.
How do I use this source code in the IE 11?

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console? If yes, try to provide the information about it. I suggest try to provide the example that we can run in the IE browser to check for the issue. It may help narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the latest version of d3, which uses ES6 features like `Set`s and `Map`s. IE11 doesn't support those features, but luckily, there are some polyfills available, like `core-js` or [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-map) specifically for Maps.

You will run into the same thing in the future, however, so you might need to either downgrade d3 to v5, or just bite the bullet and polyfill the problems as you encounter them.